# Removing a row via jQuery, how to show "No Data" message if table is empty?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

With jQuery DataTables, a table automatically shows the message, "No data available in table" if it is empty on loading.

I am using AJAX to delete some rows, and it may be that the table is emptied this way.

How can I set this "no data" message, when using jQuery .remove(), when the last row is removed from the data table?

Or should I be using an AJAX source for the table, and somehow recall the new data after doing a delete, to repopulate the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling reload method in datatable plugin API will do it automatically for you

refer the following link to know how to reload the datatable

https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Thought as much! Time to change all my table to AJAX sources :D

Comment: what type of binding are you using now to populate the data ?

Comment: Just looping through an object and outputting it to the DOM

Comment: Yes. But I will change it to use the AJAX source.

Comment: yeh that will be good because we just give the data to the plugin and they will do all other things. less work for programmer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70215/discussion-between-frebin-francis-and-mr-pablo).